# Browsers don't get compressed pages at Windows 7 64-bit OS

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, compression

I have a weird issue in my Windows 7 64-bit PC at work. I administer a few Linux web servers that serve gzipped content (js, css, html). The weird behaviour is that when all browsers in my system (Firefox, Chrome, Vivaldi) request content from those Linux servers (I can see the `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` header just fine), they do not get it. All responses come with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, so the content is not served compressed. However, running `curl` at command line with the `--compressed` option, the response comes with `Content-Type: gzip` and `Content-Length` headers and it's gzipped as it's supposed to be. From a Windows 2008 R2 server, the content is served as gzipped.

Serving the content as gzipped works fine at those Linux web servers, that is guaranteed.

There is a pfSense proxy involved, but even if I override it in proxy settings so that the browser asks for the content directly from the Linux servers, the behaviour is the same. No change, with or without the proxy.

I confirmed the issue with Firefox and Chrome with another Windows 7 64-bit PC. So, I arrive at the conclusion that the OS is somehow involved in this strange browser behaviour.

Can someone confirm...?

Comment: Unclear: Does this problem happen only on one PC?

Comment: @harrymc No, it happens at least in two, mine and a colleague's with the same OS.

Comment: Does it work with other PCs?

Comment: I wrote in my question that from a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, the browser gets compressed output. Furthermore, I tried a Windows XP 32-bit VM and it works there too. There are a few Windows 10 machines to try, but I can't do that right now.

Comment: What happens when using `Accept-Encoding: gzip` without `deflate`?

Comment: Note: It seems entirely normal that if the server pipes the output to gzip, and then pipes directly to the browser without writing the data to disk to compute the file size, then the server needs to return a chunked stream, since the length of the entire answer is unknown to start with.

Comment: Same behaviour even with just gzip. Page is served uncompressed with chunked transfer-encoding. Your comment about the web server not knowing beforehand the content size is correct, but even in the case of css or js files where the size is known the files are served with chunked encoding, thus not compressed.

Comment: Are the files being served truly unzipped?

Comment: Well, if I can't trust what the browser shows in network tool... How can I check if the files are transfered as compressed?

Comment: You may use Fiddler or Wireshark and post enough of the communication stream.

Comment: Ok, I will do that and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, Wireshark shed the light in this case. After capturing the HTTP stream between the client and the server both when deflate was used and without it, it shows that the HTTP conversation is indeed compressed in the case when mod_deflate is enabled. So, the final conclusion is that compression is actually used, but for some reason the browsers don't show that. Tried with a Windows 10 64-bit PC and the same thing (chunked is shown everywhere where compression was supposed to be used). At least I now know that compression is *actually* used.

Comment: It seems my first analysis was correct, so I added an answer (which you could accept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be deceiving : 
In order to send the gzipp'ed file in one message, the server needs to have the
entire file available and know its size, which doesn't apparently happen
in your case, as you yourself said:

> running curl at command line with the `--compressed` option, the response comes with `Content-Type: gzip` and `Content-Length` headers and it's gzipped as it's supposed to be.

I think that in your case the server *pipes* the output to gzip, and then pipes
the result directly to the browser without first writing the data to disk in
order to compute the file size.
Not knowing beforehand the size, the server has no choice but to return a stream
with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in as many parts as will become available.

As data becomes available, it will be returned in chunks, to be re-assembled
by the browser.
However, the received data is still gzipp'ed, even if received in chunks.